How to get permanent oauth 2.0 access token for Firebase Cloud Messaging in Mobile App
Team
I am developing chat mobile app (React Native) and using firebase cloud messaging for this purpose.
Wanna to use HTTP v1 API, not Legacy because Legacy API will stopped by June this year.
If I use HTTP v1 API, I have to use oAuth 2.0 access token, right?
But oAuth Playground provides only temp access toke, not temporary token.
So if it expired, I have to regenerate the access token.
How can solve this issuse on my end?
Thank you.
Best regards.
I tried to config my own OAuth Crednetial in the config panel of OAuth Playground, but can not sure the exact method to do that.
I have inputted my Client ID and ServerKey of Lagacy API of my Firebase dashboard.
But not successful.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As per my knowledge, it's not possible only short live tokens are available in OAuth 2.0 for FCM API.

If so, how can handle the short-lived token?
I have to get those tokens every 1 hour? (That token expires within 1 hour.)
